# Can't post simple form date in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

This i'm sure is a simple overlook, but its given me quite a headache in a short time period.

Im trying to post data from this view:

```
<?php
if (!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) 
    {
        echo "<a href='index.php/auth/login'>Login</a>";
    } else { ?>
<form method="POST" action="create_community">
    <label>Community Name: </label><input type="text" name="communityname" value="231"/><br>
    <label>Description: </label><br><textarea name="communitydesc"></textarea><br>
    <label>Image Location(URL): </label><input type="text" name="imageloc"/><br>
    <input type="radio" name="privacy" value="public" /> public<br />
    <input type="radio" name="privacy" value="private" /> private<br />
    <input type="radio" name="privacy" value="business" /> business<br />
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>        
<?php    }
?>
```

create controller is the following:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Create extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
        $this->load->library('encrypt');
        $this->load->library('session');

        $this->load->model('topbar_model');
        $this->load->model('left_model');
        $this->load->model('right_model');
        /*
        $this->load->model('right_model');
        $this->load->model('left_model');
        $this->load->model('topic_model');
        */
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form_helper');
        $this->load->helper('form');

        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('security');
        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
        $this->lang->load('tank_auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
            $this->load->view('create_community');
    }

    public function create_community()
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/head');
            echo "testing"; 
            print_r($this->input->post());
        }

}
```

create_community shows "testing" but does not show the post. I've tried posting individual input contents as well, and just get nothing.

Any ideas?

Comment: just saw something: my view has the same name as function...nope that didn't do anything

Comment: Can you try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to your `index.php` and see if there's any error?

Comment: Try `print_r($this->input->get_post());` to check if browser is obeying the `method="POST"` of the form. Also, using Firebug or Chrome developer console, check the Network tab to see if the browser is indeed sending post data. You can try also `print_r($_POST);` and `print_r($_REQUEST);` to check if form data is arriving at the PHP side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The believe $this->input->get_post() is a method call, not a class variable, so you can't handle like you would $_POST[].

If you are wanting to follow traditional form processing using POST, use the standard $_POST[] assoc. array, but be aware that there might be a CSRF field that will be included, and that you will need to handle.

Also, I don't know how you are routing, but shouldn't your form action be 'create/create_community', unless you are routing past 'create' for all calls at this point.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that.  Since its just a create page (That won't be in my actual site), i actually have the full URL in the form action.  I just edited it out for this post.

Comment: Oh WoW! thanks.  You reminded me that you can't put the http:// into a form action.  Of course the problem would be the one thing that I edited out! Sorry everyone. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function create_community()
{
        var_dump($this->input->post());
}
```

Comment: returns a blank document...well, returns the 'head' view.

Comment: ...well thats what your function does - what else are you expecting?

Comment: just try `print_r($_POST);` and tell us the result - at least we will know if it is a Code Igniter issue or not

Comment: Well... we are assuming you are clicking the "submit" button of the form, right? In this case, the issue seems something with the HTTP server or PHP configuration... Please, try changing the form action to `action="js/test.php"` and then create **js/test.php** file containing only `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` - maybe you are loosing your POST data in the HTTP server redirection that CI uses! Check your Apache or NginX URL rewriting config.

Comment: I did what you said, and it returned another empty array.  I don't use a local apcache server, I upload my stuff to a webhost. The other forms outside this project(a fresh CI install) are working fine...

Comment: @J.Bruni Thanks for the help, but I figured out it was just my stupidity in entering the form action, putting the full URL.